# Install ios-webkit-debug-proxy on Bitbar real device

Tags: ios, testing, appium, bitbar, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

I am trying to test an iOS application using appium on a Bitbar real device.

I start my test by executing an appium test and after the login I need to switch to WEB_VIEW context to continue testing. I did some research and found that I need to have ios-webkit-debug-proxy installed on the device to switch the context from NATIVE to WEB_VIEW.

Found this doc : http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/#building-ios-webkit-debug-proxy-from-source on the same

But how do I install ios-webkit-debug-proxy and run those commands mentioned in the doc in a Bitbar device.

Answer (score 0):

It is installed in virtual machines. You just have to set `startIWDP` to true in desired capabilities.